# Black screen Destop takes a long time when Windows booting

Tags: windows-7, boot

My laptop has a problem. The problem occured when Windows 7 booting. After please wait and welcome screen, the next progress should be to Desktop with wallpapers. But, in my laptop, i must be waiting for a few minutes, caused by black/blank screen wallpaper (with the taskbar). Black screen makes my windows takes longer time to Desktop Readiness. How do i solve the problem? the problem makes me frustrated.

Comment: Do you have external USB drives?

Comment: no, i don't. I never plug an external usb drive while booting.